# Google big query ranking order with customer hits problem

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ranking

I am using google big query to track some customers hits into my website. I am following a simple ruleset being that:

1. I only want to see the first hit source if a customer has come through the same source multiple times consecutively on the SAME day.
2. I only want to see the first hit source if a customer has come through the same source multiple times consecutively on DIFFERENT days.
3. I want to see ALL hit sources if they appear on the same day but not consecutively.

Currently, I am using the following:

```
rank() over (partition by customer_code, hit_source order by hit_timedate) rnk
```

This allows me to fulfil the first 2 steps if I filter on "where rnk = 1". This will only give me the distinct hit sources whether or not they are on the same day because i have a time within the hit_timedate. But it does not give me the 3rd step because the ranking is partitioned by the hit_source and will change when it sees the same source.

If anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Unsure how to add/upload a sample dataset so I've tried to do it here:

```
Customer_Code       Hit_Source               Hit_Timedate
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 10:30am
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 11:45am
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 11:55am
     101             Twitter              25/05/2020 12:30am
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 13:00pm 
     101             Google               25/05/2020 15:00pm
     101             Instagram            26/05/2020 09:00am
```

The desired result set would ideally be something like this:

```
Customer_Code       Hit_Source               Hit_Timedate        Rank
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 10:30am       1
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 11:45am       2
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 11:55am       3
     101             Twitter              25/05/2020 12:30am       1
     101             Facebook             25/05/2020 13:00pm       1
     101             Google               25/05/2020 15:00pm       1
     101             Instagram            26/05/2020 09:00am       1
```

So, according to my rules I want to implement above.. the main problem I have here is being able to rank the 5th row in the sample as '1'. I want to do this because the last two 'Facebook' hits were not consecutive. But being able to do this with the first 2 rules I have implemented I am struggling with.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, could you please share sample data and expected results? So, it is better to create a query and test it.

Comment: Hello, sample and desired result set added as an edition to my original post. THanks.

Comment: @dbdbdb1993, why is Facebook at 25/05/2020 13:00pm in rank 1 not 4?

Comment: Hello Alexandre, it is because the 4th facebook row is not consecutive, as there were different hit_sources prior so it resets back to rank 1, this is the logic i plan to implement. I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative count:

```
select t.*,
       1 + countif(prev_source = source) over (partition by customer_code, datetime_trunc(hit_timedate, day) order by hit_timedate) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             lag(source) over (partition by customer_code, datetime_trunc(hit_timedate, day)
                               order by hit_timedate
                              ) as prev_source
     from t
    ) t;
```

The idea is to create a flag as to whether the previous source is the same as the current row -- if it is not, then add 1.  The `1 +` is because the count will start at `0` and you want the counts to start at `1`.

Comment: Hello, using Alexandres example of his CTE to manually insert the dataset.. this seems to give me a rank of 3 for every single row. I need to have the ranking as i have specified in the desired result set. This way i can filter on where the ranking = 1 etc. etc.

Comment: @dbdbdb1993 . . . The `countif()` needs an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In order to further contribute to the community I will share a different approach using [LAG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lag), [SUM()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#sum), [CASE WHEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case_expr) and the [MIN()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#min) built-in functions for BigQuery.

Below is the code divided into 2 steps (commented within) with the sample data you provided:

```
with data as (
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Facebook" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,10,30,00) as Hit_Timedate UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Facebook" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,11,45,0) as Hit_Timedate UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Facebook" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,11,55,0) as Hit_Timedate UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Twitter" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,12,30,0) as Hit_Timedate UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Facebook" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,13,00,0) as Hit_Timedate UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Google" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,15,00,0) as Hit_Timedate UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as Customer_Code,"Instagram" as Hit_Source ,DATETIME(2020,05,25,09,00,0) as Hit_Timedate 
),
#step 1
data1 as (
SELECT Customer_Code, Hit_Source, Hit_Timedate, LAG(Hit_Source,1) OVER (ORDER BY Hit_Timedate) as PrevHit from data
),
#step 2
data2 as (
SELECT Customer_Code, Hit_Source,PrevHit , Hit_Timedate, SUM(CASE WHEN Hit_Source = PrevHit THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Hit_Timedate,Hit_Source) AS rank_aux
FROM data1
)

SELECT Customer_Code, Hit_Source, MIN(Hit_Timedate) AS first_Hit_Timedate, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY rank_aux order by Hit_Timedate) as rank FROM data2 
GROUP BY Customer_Code, Hit_Source, rank_aux,Hit_Timedate
ORDER BY Customer_Code,first_Hit_Timedate, Hit_Source
```

***And the final output,***

```
Row Customer_Code   Hit_Source  first_Hit_Timedate  rank
1   101             Instagram   2020-05-25T09:00:00 1
2   101             Facebook    2020-05-25T10:30:00 1
3   101             Facebook    2020-05-25T11:45:00 2
4   101             Facebook    2020-05-25T11:55:00 3
5   101             Twitter     2020-05-25T12:30:00 1
6   101             Facebook    2020-05-25T13:00:00 1
7   101             Google      2020-05-25T15:00:00 1
```

Notice that in ***step 1***, a new column with the previous value for `Hit_Source` is created. Afterwards in step 2, a new column `rank_aux` is created in order to aggregate correctly the results. Below is the output for ***step 2*** (only for explanation purposes):

```
Row Customer_Code   Hit_Source  PrevHit     Hit_Timedate        rank_aux
1   101             Instagram   null        2020-05-25T09:00:00 1
2   101             Facebook    Instagram   2020-05-25T10:30:00 2
3   101             Facebook    Facebook    2020-05-25T11:45:00 2
4   101             Facebook    Facebook    2020-05-25T11:55:00 2
5   101             Twitter     Facebook    2020-05-25T12:30:00 3
6   101             Facebook    Twitter     2020-05-25T13:00:00 4
7   101             Google      Facebook    2020-05-25T15:00:00 5
```

Paying attention to the 2nd,3rd and 4th rows where `rank_aux=2`, which was the desired output so it is possible to aggregate these columns into 1 and displaying only the minimum `Hit_Timedate` to obtain the final output, already shared.

Comment: Hello, this does not match my desired result set as per my original question. Please pay attention to the desired result set 'rank' specifically. The 1st and 4th instance of Facebook should be rank 1 because the previous hit source was not Facebook.

Comment: @dbdbdb1993, Hi thanks for letting me know. So the idea is that after we have a column which allow us to group consecutive actions, it is possible to rank. Therefore, you just just use the RANK() function within the last part of the code. I have uploaded the code and output with the new ones. Did you check it? Please, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.